# constructor not accepting my information

Tags: java, object, constructor

so the constuctor is saying ) expected, error not a statement and ; expected

```
    Person num1, num2, num3;
    num1=new Person(Allison, 6600 Crescent Ave, 32, 9024231421);
    num2=new Person(George, 5251 Lakewood St, 24, 9024489216);
    num3=new Person(Michael, 2429 Inglis St, 56, 9024212345);
```

object class

```
   public Person() {
   }
//constructor allows programmer to define variable values in demo class
   public Person(String nm, String adr, int ag, long phn) {
    name=nm;
    address=adr;
    age=ag;
    phoneNumber=phn;
 }
```

Comment: String should be in double quotes as explained in answer by @Burkhard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
num1=new Person(Allison, 6600 Crescent Ave, 32, 9024231421);
```

should be

```
num1=new Person("Allison", "6600 Crescent Ave", 32, 9024231421);
```

String, String, int and long are expected in this order by your constructor, which is defined by `public Person(String nm, String adr, int ag, long phn)`.

Allison without (double)quotes is not a String.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a string for Name and Address to your constructor, try changing

```
num1=new Person(Allison, 6600 Crescent Ave, 32, 9024231421);
```

to

```
num1=new Person("Allison", "6600 Crescent Ave", 32, 9024231421);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

First you can check your `Person` class object is created.

Print some message in

```
 public Person() {
      System.out.println("in default constructor");
 }
```

if you can not see any print statement then problem with object.

**Step 2:**

Check what you pass and passed value is `print or not`.

If not print then problem `with your parameter(argument)`.

**Your Problem:**

You are `not passing actual string value`,You have to pass string value wihin `""`

```
num1=new Person("Allison", "6600 Crescent Ave", 32, 9024231421);
```

**Many SO user give actually answer but this stuff is for feature reader so user can see and don't take mistake next time.**

Comment: Strange way of putting it. Step 1 is completely pointless until the code compiles, which doesn't happen until you fix step 2.

Comment: If you are just create simple object with no parameter and check when the object is created.then it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling construtor that in not exist for your first argument you have defined string so pass in double quote while calling construtor

Answer (score 0):

Because strings are always used within the double quotes . put your arguments which are strings  in the  double quotes.